# Is this a circular dependency? How can I fix it?

Tags: c++

I believe I am having a circular dependency problem.  I researched other answers but I do not understand how to use the forward declaration to fix my problem.

I have the following composition:

```
+------------------+
|Session  <---------------+
|                  |      |
|  +------------+  | Must know
|  |Dataset     |  |   about
|  |            |  |      ^
|  |            |  |      |
|  |            +---------+
|  |            |  |
|  |            |  |
|  +------------+  |
|                  |
+------------------+
```

From the code posted below, can you spot any circular dependencies or problems?  I can post more code if necessary.  It's a complex system and I'm trying to boil the issue down to it's most basic part.

**Session.h**

```
#include "Dataset.h"

...

namespace bmd2 {

class Session {

  private:
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<bmd2::Dataset>> 
        datasetContainer;  // error here
```

**Dataset.h**

```
#include "Session.h"  // when I include this line I get strange errors

namespace bmd2 {

class Dataset {

  private:
    bmd::Session & session;
```

Some of the errors I get when I make Dataset aware of Session is:

Session.h `Dataset in namespace bmd2 does not name a type`

### First try

So I tried this:

**Dataset.h**

```
// removed include
namespace bmd2 {

class Dataset {

  class Session;

  private:
    bmd2::Session & session;
```

**Dataset.cpp**

```
#include "Session.h"

bmd2::Dataset::Dataset(bmd2::Session & _session,
                       bmd2::Logger & _logger,
                       const std::string & filePath,
                       bmd2::File::FileMode fileMode)
                       : session(_session), logger(_logger)
{
```

and I still get: 'Session" in namespace bmd2 does not name a type.  This is so frustrating.

Comment: Do your header files contain "include guards" to ensure they are never included anywhere more than once?  (Perhaps you've removed them here for brevity.)  These are critical!

Comment: Yes they do!  They sure do.

Comment: Regarding the update: you need to declare `Session` in the namespace, not inside `Dataset`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you can't have both headers including the other. Luckily, `Dataset` doesn't need the full definition of `Session` just to declare a reference to one; just declare the class (inside its namespace):

```
class Session;
```

Make sure this is in the namespace; your update indicates you've put it inside `Dataset`, which declares a different class in a different scope.

Comment: What would happen if Dataset needed more than just the declaration?  Is that something that ever really comes up in C++ projects?

Comment: @jakeliquorblues: It's rare for that to happen, since two classes can't logically contain each other (although it could if, for example, you want `A` to contain `B` and `B` to contain `vector<A>`, since `vector` requires a complete type for some reason). When it does happen, you might need to add an extra layer of indirection to break one of the direct dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Your dataset contains only a reference to `Session`, so you do not need the definition for the `Session` class there it is enough to just declare it in the header like:

**Dataset.h**

```
namespace bmd2 {

class Session; //class declaration

class Dataset {

  private:
    bmd::Session & session;
```

and the include moves to the cpp file so your class can use its methods as well in the implementation:

**Dataset.cpp**

```
#include "Session.h"

...
```

This is called forward declaration. See detailed info at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/c-forward-declaration).

Comment: @jakeliquorblues: _"and I still get: 'Session" in namespace bmd2 does not name a type. This is so frustrating."_ - you put Session inside your Dataset class. That is valid (it will be a nested class) through this is not what you want now.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only hold references (pointers will also work) and not actual instances, if you follow these steps closely, you will build and link fine:

1. Make sure you have `#pragma once` or include guards at the top of all your .h files
2. Create a `fwd.hpp` file that has forward declarations for Session and DataSet
3. Make sure your `Session.hpp` and `Data.hpp` don't have implementation details that invoke each other's functions.  If you do, put them in your .cpp files and use the appropriate cross-hpp there.
4. In your `Session.hpp` and `Data.hpp`, only include `fwd.hpp` - do not include each other's headers.

This procedure will also work great if your two classes hold references or pointers to each other.  As long as you keep your cross-function calls in your .cpp file (adjustments can be made for template classes if you have to invoke from the header).